# Why does list.size change when executing java parallel stream?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

Consider the following code:

```
static void statefullParallelLambdaSet() {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    );
    
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum = s.parallelStream().mapToInt(e -> {    // pipeline start
        if (list.size() <= 3) {     // list.size() changes while the pipeline operation is executing.
            list.add(e);            // mapToInt's lambda expression depends on this value, so it's stateful.
            return e;
        }
        else return 0;
    }).sum();   // terminal operation

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

In the code above, it says that `list.size()` changes while the pipe operation is running, but I don't understand.

Since `list.add(e)` is executed at once in multiple threads because it is executed in parallel, is it correct to assume that the value changes each time it is executed?

The reason why the value changes even if it is executed as a serial stream is that there is no order because it is a set, so the number drawn is different each time it is executed...

Am I right?

Comment: This is because of a race condition, you need to actually understand parallel computing, we also have to know this stuff for HPC workloads, you should never rely on data being altered by threads without using locks https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-locks

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this happens is because of what is called race conditions CPU even many threaded ones are running more processes than just your applications processes so it could parse and instruction evaluate it and then have to jump off to do something for the OS and then come back and another parallel process for your application has managed to get past it because the core / hyper-thread has not been stolen from its job.

you can read about race conditions in books like: https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-0-387-09766-4_36

But what you're supposed to do to prevent this is implemented locks on the memory you're altering, in Java you want to look at `java.util.concurrent.Locks` https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-locks

Answer (score 0):

***Note** that the problem itself is slightly artificial, because it's not very likely to get a significant performance gain by parallelizing this task.*

## Issues Explained

Your code accumulates the result by operating via side-effects which is **discouraged** by the [*Stream API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

And you've stumbled on the very first bullet point from the link above:

> ... there are **no guarantees** as to:
>
> - the visibility of those side-effects to other threads;

`ArrayList` is not a thread-safe Collection, and as a consequence each thread is not guaranteed to observe the same state of the list.

Also, note that `map()` operation (*and all it's flavors*) is not intended to perform side-effects and it's function according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) should be **stateless**:

> `mapper` - a non-interfering, **stateless function** to apply to each element

In this case, the correct way to incorporate from processing the previous stream elements would be to define a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

For that we would need to define a mutable container which would hold a list

In a nut-shell, Collector can be implemented as concurrent (*i.e. optimized for a multithreaded environment, so that all the threads are updating the same mutable container*) or non-concurrent (*each thread creates its own instance of the mutable container and populates it, then results produces by each thread are getting merged*).

In order to implement a concurrent Collector, we need to provide a thread-safe mutable container and specify a characteristic `CONCURRENT`. If take a look at the implementations of the `List` interface, you'll find out that the only options that JDK offers are `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and outdated `Verctor`.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` would be a terrible choice since under the hood it would create a new list with every added element, that's a recipe on how to get an `OutOfMemoryError`. This Collection is not suitable for frequent updates.

And if we would use a synchronized `List` it would buy anything in terms of performance, because threads would **not** be able to operate on this list simultaneously. While one thread is adding an element, the others are blocked. In fact, it would be **slower** than processing the data **sequentially**, because synchronization has a cost.

*For that reason, Locking suggested in another answer would only allow to get a correct result, but you would not be able to benefit from the parallel execution.*

What we can do is create a non-concurrent Collector (*i.e. a collector that uses a non-thread-safe container*) based on a plain `ArrayList` (*it still would be able to be used with a parallel stream, each thread would act independently on a separate container without locking and running into concurrency-related issues*).

## Non-concurrent Collector

Firstly, we need to define a custom accumulation type that encapsulates the `ArrayList` and the `sum` of consumed elements.

And in order to create a Collector, we need to use static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

*Collector:*

```
public static Collector<Integer, ?, IntSumContainer> toParallelIntSumContainer(int limit) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new IntSumContainer(limit),
        IntSumContainer::accept,
        IntSumContainer::merge
    );
}
```

*Custom accumulation type:*

```
public class IntSumContainer implements IntConsumer {
    private int sum;
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int limit;

    public IntSumContainer(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(int value) {
        if (list.size() < limit) {
            list.add(value);
            sum += value;
        }
    }
    
    public IntSumContainer merge(IntSumContainer other) {
        other.list.stream().limit(limit - list.size()).forEach(this::accept); // there couldn't be issues related to concurrent access in the case, hence performing side-effects via forEach is safe 
        return this;
    }
    
    // getters
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
List<Integer> source = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

IntSumContainer result = s.parallelStream()
    .collect(toIntSumContainer(3));

List<Integer> list = result.getList();
int sum = result.getSum();

System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(sum);
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2, 3]
6
```

## Concurrent Collector

Since you're using as a stream source a `HashSet`, which produces an **unordered** stream, probably it might be not important which elements would be present in the resulting collection and would contribute to the resulting sum. And since you were using a Set, you might be fine with getting a Set as a result as well.

In this case we can make use of the concurrent HashSet which is provided by the JDK in the form of a view over the keys of the `ConcurrentHashMap` and can be obtained via static method [`ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#newKeySet(int)). The implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap` is **lock-free**.

To accumulate the sum concurrently, we can use a [`LongAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html) which is more performant than `AtomicLong` when frequent updates are required because of not being synchronized (which is the case here).

Like in the previous example, a custom accumulation type would  encapsulate the `Set` and the `sum` of consumed elements.

While defining collector, in order to make it concurrent we need to specify the characteristic `CONCURRENT`, and `UNORDERED` would also be handy since we stated that the ordering is not important.

*Collector:*

```
public static Collector<Integer, ?, ConcurrentIntSumContainer> toConcurrentIntSumContainer(int limit) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new ConcurrentIntSumContainer(limit),
        ConcurrentIntSumContainer::accept,
        (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError("merge function is not expected be called by the Parallel collector"); },
        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED, Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT
    );
}
```

*Custom accumulation type:*

```
public class ConcurrentIntSumContainer implements IntConsumer {
    private LongAdder sum = new LongAdder();
    private Set<Integer> set = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    private final int limit;
    
    public ConcurrentIntSumContainer(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void accept(int value) {
        if (set.size() < limit && set.add(value)) {
            sum.add(value);
        }
    }
    
    public Set<Integer> getSet() {
        return new HashSet<>(set); // because a general purpose set is faster than concurrent set
    }
    
    public long getSum() {
        return sum.sum();
    }
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
List<Integer> source = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

ConcurrentIntSumContainer result1 = source.parallelStream()
    .collect(toConcurrentIntSumContainer(3));
    
Set<Integer> set = result1.getSet();
long sum = result1.getSum();
    
System.out.println(set);
System.out.println(sum);
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 4, 5]
10
```